# How do I make a counter start with 1?

Tags: counters

I defined a counter like this:

```
\newcounter{my_steps}[subsubsection]
```

and I would like to make it start with 1 instead of 0 after each subsubsection. How?

Comment: I guess you can wrap the `subsubsection` command and `\setcounter{counter}{value}` into a new command.

Comment: good idea, I'll go for that one

Answer (score 5):

Using the `etoolbox` package you can patch the `\subsubsection` command so that the counter is set to 1 with every use of `\subsubsection`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{myc}[subsubsection]
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\setcounter{myc}{1}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Test}
\themyc
\subsubsection{Test}
\themyc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the counter `mycount` (say) is only used for display purposes, you could also just modify the display part of it - `\themycount`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycount}[subsubsection]% mycount is slave to master subsubsection
\renewcommand{\themycount}{\number\numexpr\value{mycount}+1\relax}% Display mycount+1
\begin{document}
\noindent \themycount \par
\noindent \stepcounter{mycount}\themycount
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\noindent \themycount \par
\noindent \stepcounter{mycount}\themycount
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\noindent \themycount
\end{document}
```

As mentioned, this is only functional in its display, since using `\setcounter{mycount}{10}` (say), will print `11` when using `\themycount`.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of ugly trick, but maybe usefull my be the manipulation of the *clear list* of counter `subsubsection`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mysteps}[subsubsection]
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\cl@subsubsection}{\stepcounter{mysteps}}% clear list manipulation
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
mysteps is \themysteps.
Adding 10 to mysteps: \addtocounter{mysteps}{10}.
mysteps is \themysteps.

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
mysteps is \themysteps.

\end{document}
```

Caveat: If you're using package [chngcntr](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) you have to do the manipulation of the *clear list* after all `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout`!

Answer (score 1):

After reading percusse's comment I decided to go with the following:

```
\newcounter{stappen}
\newcommand{\stepreset}{\setcounter{stappen}{0}}
\newcommand{\step}{\stepcounter{stappen} \textbf{Stap \arabic{stappen}} }
```

I re-use the counter during the document and reset it when needed with `\stepreset`. This is more flexible than bind it to the subsubsection counter. Every time I need a step printed I just type: `\step`.

Comment: You could also use `\refstepcounter{stappen}` instead of `\stepcounter{stappen}` if you want to be able to reference your steps (using `\label` and `\ref`).